# Detect Google Maps Javascript API limit for map loads

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to detect whether my website hit the 25k limit for map loads. I already had a look at the [Maps JS API reference](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=nl) but it only lists the possibility to check the status for things like the Geocoding API but not the Map load itself.

So I am not interested in the limits related to geocoding or place lookup but just the limit on displaying interactive maps.

Any idea how I can detect if the limit is hit and no map will be displayed?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not aware of any programmatic way to query the API for your usage. You can access a lot of information from the API console though. https://console.developers.google.com/ Select your project, click *APIs & Auth*, click *APIs*, select the desired API and click *Reports*

Comment: Ok thanks you.. Do you know if there is an error thrown once the limit is hit and the map cant be initialized anymore?

Comment: From the documentation: *If your site or application generates 25 000 map loads or more each day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we’ll get in touch with you to talk about payment. Don’t worry, if you go over the limits, we won’t immediately shut off your API access or display error messages on your site.* https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage

Comment: Yes I am aware of this fair use policy.. just wanted to make sure if there is any programmatic check as well to be 100% fail safe. Thanks for your efforts!