# Detect query limit message on map load with Google Maps Javascript Api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem with Google Maps Javascript Api.
I want to detect if my daily limit quota of 25,000 map loads per 24 hours as described [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) is reached.

I already searched for a lot of similar questions, as [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25362010/detect-google-maps-javascript-api-limit-for-map-loads), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24430147/detect-google-maps-api-quota-limit), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14014074/google-maps-api-over-query-limit-per-second-limit), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665696/how-to-detect-that-the-25000-request-per-day-limit-has-been-reached-in-google-ma)], but they:

- have no useful response (1)
- use other Api and not Google Maps Javascript Api (2)
- refers to geocoding and not map loading (3)
- use Google Api Console (4)

The only question that I find useful is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45201174/how-to-catch-overquotamaperror-for-a-google-map).
It refers to [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events#auth-errors), that says:

> If you want to programmatically detect an authentication failure (for example to automatically send an beacon) you can prepare a callback function. If the following global function is defined it will be called when the authentication fails. function gm_authFailure() { /* Code */ };

If I have a simple script like this:

```
    <script>
    function initMap() {
        var map;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: { lat: 42.345, lng: 12.46 }
        });
    }
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
```

How can I implement  function gm_authFailure(), in order to detect query limit reached?

I'm new to Js and have no clue how to do that. Can you give me some examples?

Answer (score 2):

you just need to define your function globally, like this

```
 <script>
    function initMap() {
        var map;
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: { lat: 42.345, lng: 12.46 }
        });
    }
    function gm_authFailure() { 
        alert("test"); // here you define your authentication failed message
    };
    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MYKEY&callback=initMap"></script>
<div id="map" style="height: 500px; width: 500px;"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know any methods to test this code? How can I programmatically call the script in order to finish my calls? I tried to call initMap recursivelly, but it didn't work

Comment: Actually this method runs when application connect with google map and authentication is failed, but you can make some logic like => in gm_authFailure function if limit exceed then hide your map showing message about limit exceed

Comment: Also can you show your code, as you are saying that it is in loop, can you show me how actually you are using

Comment: Sorry for bad formatting, but I just called something like: `for (i = 0; i < 50000; i++) { var map;
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                zoom: 7,
                center: { lat: 42.345, lng: 12.46 }
            });
            }`

Comment: seeing your code, i understand , that you are showing 5000 map on single page, is this your requirement? if i am not wrong, are you want to add multiple markers/pin on map?

Comment: My requirement is to finish my key query limit. I tried to load the map multiple times not because I need 50000 map, but because I need to finish google query limit. If there is another method to do it, I will try.

Comment: You might also want to star the following feature request in Google issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35830575. It requests a programmatic way to check current usage for Google Maps APIs.

Comment: I tried this code with a 25000 finished requests key and it doesn't work. Maybe gm_AuthFailure function doesn't recognise OverQueryLimit error.